# How can I make advanced search in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to make advance search in ASP.NET MVC with different parameters. I started with simple view model first, but it does not work.
This is my view model:

```
public class ViewModesTest
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreateDateTime { get; set; }
}
```

And i made a partial view for search result,this is the code for search:

```
   public ActionResult MemberSearch()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult MemberSearch(ViewModesTest m)
    {
        var d = db.Members.Where(s => s.Name == m.Name && m.LastName).ToList();
        return PartialView("SearchResutl");
    }
    public ActionResult SearchResutl()
    {
        return PartialView();
    }
```

Comment: what do you mean by advance search ? how you passing the d in your SearchResutl page

Comment: Define advance search. Realize this has nothing to do with asp.netmvc - you may actually have to do some real programming on the database side for anything fancy. Which will make this either an entity framework (you use that, right) or even a sql server question.

Comment: public ActionResult MemberSearch(ViewModesTest m)
    {
        var d = db.Members.Where(s => s.Name == m.Name && m.LastName).ToList();
        return PartialView("SearchResutl",d);
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see your code, it have 2 problems:

1. You get data but don't return data for View.
2. When return PartialView, We are can't "public ActionResult SearchResutl()", It can remove.

Code fix same that:

```
public ActionResult MemberSearch()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult MemberSearch(ViewModesTest m)
    {
        var d = db.Members.Where(s => s.Name == m.Name && m.LastName).ToList();
        return PartialView("SearchResutl", d);
    }
```

And outside View u can call model class `@model List<Members>`